# Best plugin for jQuery and Google Maps API v3?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I've been looking for a jQuery plugin to load a gMaps using Google Maps API v3.

What are the jQuery plugins you use in this case?

At the moment, jMapping is the best I've found:

https://github.com/brianjlandau/jmapping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a good experience using [$.goMap](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/). I didn't push it to far, though, so YMMV.

Answer (score 21):

I might be a bit bias here, but **I would recommend** [jquery.ui.map - jQuery Google maps v3 plugin for UI and jQuery mobile](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/), since it can populate a map from microdata, microformats and rdfa, thus search engine friendly :) plus it's small and easy to use.

---

**Gmap3 4.1**:

*Positive*: Seems to have alot of functions, like it's own clustering (I havn't tested it properly)

*Negative*: It's big (29kB) and the syntax is slightly confusing (I havn't tested it properly).

*Total size*: 29kB

---

**jMapping 2.1.0**:

*Positive*: Good for SEO and usability since you always have to have an html list present.

*Negative*: Not using standard metadata and use of data attribute, alot overhead, not flexible, lacking alot of features

*Total size*: 49kB - jMapping 6kB + jQuery metadata 5kB + markermanager 29kB + Styledmarker 9kB

I wouldn't consider building anything more complex than 'this is my office' or 'parks in our city'.

---

**goMap 1.3.2**:

*Positive*: Kind of easy to use. Better than jMapping when it comes to having more features

*Negative*: Still lacking alot of features, not flexible

*Total size*: 11kB

I would use this over jMapping for more complex implementations, however it seems I'd still have to write alot of native Google maps code.

---

**jquery.ui.map v.3**:

*Positive*: Easy to use, split into several js files (or one) for your implementation needs. Can read from standardized metadata (microdata, microformats, RDFa) which means it's good for SEO and usability, easy to override any function or add new functions without hacking the core.

*Negative*: It has alot of options, which might add complexity for people not used to the plugin and/or jQuery.

*Total size alt. 1*: 4kB - jquery.ui.map.min.full.js (4kB)

*Total size alt. 2*: 5-7kB - jquery.ui.map.min.full.js (4kB), jquery.ui.rdfa.min.js/jquery.ui.microformat.min.js/jquery.ui.microdata.min.js (1-3kB)

Other jquery google maps plugins can be found [here](http://slodive.com/web-development/15-jquery-google-map-plugins/)

Comment: Johan, I think you should move your project over to github and work on improving the sourcecode a bit.. sorry but the project seems abandoned (as most of the jquery google plugins to be honest!)

Comment: @johansalllarsson> Is jquery-ui-map still being worked on? I noticed that v3 has been release candidate for more than one year. Thanks!

Comment: @George Katsanos>  Did you find any good alternative to jquery-ui-map?

Comment: I used Leaflet.js which is so modern and well-thought that comparing it with stuff like jquery-ui-map would be a joke.

Comment: jMapping is no longer compatible with jQuery

Comment: Currently the best I have found: http://gmap3.net/

Answer (score 1):

Also [here](http://speckyboy.com/2010/02/03/10-jquery-plugins-for-easier-google-map-installation/) are some plugins gathered so you can see some demos and maybe test some of them.

Comment: If what you want is a simple lightweight plugin that allows you to add a custom marker and include directions then you should check out my blog post -> http://www.fryed.co.uk/blog/jquery-google-map-plugin.  I have used it on hundreds of websites as its so quick to implement. Perfect for a websites contact us page.

Comment: jMapping is no longer compatible with jQuery